# rails http response to Donwload excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-5

i saw this code in github

```
require "csv"

csv_str = CSV.generate do |csv|
 csv << ["awesome", "csv"]
end

result = IO.popen("secure-spreadsheet --password secret", "r+") do |io|
 io.write(csv_str)
 io.close_write
 io.read
end

File.open("output.xlsx", "w") { |f| f.write(result) }
```

this code store a Excel file(output.xlsx) in my project file.

how can i convert this "store file scenario" in to "download the file in the browser"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config/initializers/mime_types.rb register the xlsx mime_type(It is not available in Rails by default)  :

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xlsx", :xlsx
```

Assuming your code that does the excel generation works and is in a controller method(private) named `excel_file` (I think its better to extract to a service/lib class):

```rb
def excel_file
  csv_str = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ["awesome", "csv"]
  end

  IO.popen("secure-spreadsheet --password secret", "r+") do |io|
    io.write(csv_str)
    io.close_write
    io.read
  end
end
```

In your controller action you should be able to do something like this

```rb
def download_excel
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx { send_data excel_file, type: 'application/xlsx; header=present', disposition: "attachment", filename: "output.xlsx"  }
  end
end
```

( [ActionController#send_data](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) "sends the given binary data to the browser". Read more via that link)

If you have a view, you can have a download link

```
<%= link_to "Download", your_download_path(format: "xlsx") %>
```

Users should be able to download the excel file via the link

Comment: let me try this my friend

Comment: i will try this in caxlsx gem i hope this will work